# Uncaught ReferenceError on click JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

I can not get the values from my button

this Uncaught ReferenceError: reply_click is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

**Note:** I want my button to continue working!

can anyone help me ?

```
  function reply_click(clicked_id){
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
    });
    console.log('attached');
    $('#openButton').on('click', function(data) {
        console.log('clicked');
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/dash",
            data: { _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr(('src','{{url('/')}}'+data)}
        })
       .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('.inputbutton input').css("background-image", "url("+data+")");
        })
        .fail(function(data){
            console.log('Error:', data);
        });
    });
});
```

}

my button from blade.php

```
<div class="inputbutton">
<span class="text">TEXT</span>
<input type="submit" class="btTxt submit" value=""  id="TEXT" onclick="reply_click(this.id)">
</div>
```

Comment: try reply_click("TEXT")

Comment: I believe the solution is at the ajax level.

Comment: What do you want when you click on the button?

Comment: change the image every time I click the button ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good practice to use onclick, besides you should put your function inside the `$(function() {})` instead

So something like this:

```
$(function() {
    function reply_click(clicked_id){
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
        ....
    }
});
```

Also consider changing onclick to using `$('#TEXT').click(function() {....})`

So overall, remove onlclick, and all of the codes should look like this:

```
$(function() {
    function reply_click(clicked_id){
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
        ....
    }

    $('#TEXT').click(function() {
        // ON CLICK ACTIONS GO HERE
        var input_id = $(this).attr('id'); // for example getting the id of the input
        ....
    })
});
```

Comment: where I change this $ ('# TEXT'). click (function () {....})? inside the button from blade.php?

Comment: What error did you receive now? The error should be different if you already remove the onclick, see my updated answer above for more clarifications if you don't know where to put $ ('# TEXT'). click (function () {....})

Comment: It worked because the button function does not exist anymore 
.-.

Comment: I want to be able to click and get the value of the function

Comment: you can get anything from the input using $(this)

I see that in the question you're trying to get thid id, which you can get using $(this).attr('id')

see updated answer